# Get numeric value without error "Subscript requires size of interface 'NSArray', which is not constant in non-stable ABI"

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray

If I have an `NSArray`, and I want to get each of the numbers in it, is there a simple way to do that?

I tried the advice from
http://code.flamingleaf.com/category/objective-c/
that said instead of (the method used in other programming languages for subscripts within arrays):

> someArray[i]

to use

> [someArray objectAtIndex:i];

Is there some way to get the numeric value?

I keep getting an error of the type: 
“Subscript requires size of interface 'NSArray', which is not constant in non-stable ABI”

Thank you for the suggestion by  Kurt Revis to put in real code.  **I could not recreate the problem.**  But this is my closest:

```
      for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
            NSLog(@"%i",[[temp objectAtIndex: i]length]);
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
            tempNumbers[i]=[[temp objectAtIndex:i] length];
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
            NSLog(@"The count at i=%i is %i", i, tempNumbers[i]);
```

and it worked as:

```
3   
3   
5   
2   
 the value of i = 0 and tempNumbers[i]=3.000000  
 the value of i = 1 and tempNumbers[i]=3.000000  
 the value of i = 2 and tempNumbers[i]=5.000000  
 the value of i = 3 and tempNumbers[i]=2.000000
```

Conclusion: Until I can write simple code to recreate the problem, I won't clog this question area.

2nd Conclusion: I will try the solution suggested by edc1591.

Comment: Show your code, specifically: the code that puts numbers into the array, and the code that takes numbers out.  This is a very basic question and you probably have something very simple wrong, but it's hard to guess exactly what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing what class the objects are, but if they are of type `NSString` or `NSNumber` you can use any of the following methods to get the numerical value:

```
[[someArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
[[someArray objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
[[someArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
[[someArray objectAtIndex:i] unsignedIntValue];
```

etc...